# Android: Store Spinner Selected Value

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have created a `spinner` that fill data from database.

Assume, user select item from `spinner` and press back button.(or any other button in my android app). then user do some other stuffs and came back to screen which user previously select item from `spinner`. in this occasion `spinners selected item` should be the item that user `previously selected`.

How cloud i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences is not really intended for this.  If you use a shared preference, the saved state may persist across different invocations of the activity - may be what you wanted, or may not be.

A better way is to use the feature intended for saving UI state - override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and write the application state values you want to change to the Bundle parameter, as shown in this answer:
[Android adding more save results to Notepad sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734743/android-adding-more-save-results-to-notepad-sample)